# How to convert string separate by enter to array with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, converters

I am newbie with Python. I would like to convert string to array.

My string comes from:

```
<Country>
     <number no="11" info="date">
          <detail name="a1" class="11a" />
               <string name="hello" />
               <string name="world" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="a2" class="1a2" />
               <string name="hello" />
               <string name="world" />
          </detail>
     </number>
<Country>
```

Code

```
XML = ET.parse(File)
for name in XML.findall('.//detail [@class="11a"]/'):
   detname = name.get('name')
   print(detname)
```

The output of `detname` is like this:

```
hello
world
```

My expectation it become `["hello","world"]`

I tried like this:

```
arr = detname.split()
print(arr)
```

I'm trying to print the type of the string like this `<class 'str'> <class 'str'>`

It return this:

```
['world']
```

It not include the `"hello"`.

Comment: try printing the string before split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Based on the update in the question as how the string is generated with:

```
for name in XML.findall('.//detail [@class="11a"]/'):
   detname = name.get('name')
   print(detname)
```

`detname` basically here represents individual names in each iteration and you print them so you get each in new line.

If your requirement is to create a list with these names, then create a list object and append individual names to the list as:

```
names = []
for name in XML.findall('.//detail [@class="11a"]/'):
   detname = name.get('name')
   names.append(detname)

print(names)
```

Further, it can be done in one line with list comprehension as:

```
names = [name.get() for name in XML.findall('.//detail [@class="11a"]/')]
print(names)
```

---

Your string is separated by new line characters.

Use `splitlines()` to split them into list:

```
string = "Hello\nWorld"
array = string.splitlines()
print(array)
```

Comment: I tried, but it still return only ['World'] @Krishna

Comment: @Joe, can you please add the full code? It looks like you are taking input as multi-line string and this probably won't work as is.

Comment: I update the question how I got the string. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If text is seperated by newlines like you wrote in comment you can use this:

```
string = "Hello\nWorld"
arr = string .split('\n')
print(arr)
```

Comment: I tried, but it still return only ['World'] @Felix

Comment: Where does the string come from exactly, "Hello"\n"World" is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = "Hello\nWorld"
arr = string.splitlines()
print(arr)
for i in arr:
    print(type(i))
```